# Problem with dynamically changing which command a button calls in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-class, tkinter-button

In this simple calculator GUI, I'm creating a frame template using classes. The frame has 2 labels, 2 entry boxes, and a button. I'd like the button to run a specific command depending on the `function_call` variable passed when initializing - but this doesn't work. The `two_points` function should be called for the first object, and `one_point` should be called for the second. How do I dynamically change which command is called based on which object I'm using? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Slope Calculator")

class Slope_Calc:
    # Variable info that changes within the frame
    def __init__(self, master, num_1, num_2, frame_name, label_1_name, label_2_name, function_call):
        self.num_1 = int(num_1)
        self.num_2 = int(num_2)
        self.frame_name = frame_name
        self.label_1_name = label_1_name
        self.label_2_name = label_2_name
        self.function_call = function_call

        # Frame template
        self.frame_1 = LabelFrame(master, text = self.frame_name, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.frame_1.grid(row = self.num_1, column = self.num_2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.label_1 = Label(self.frame_1, text = self.label_1_name)
        self.label_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.entry_1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.label_2 = Label(self.frame_1, text = self.label_2_name)
        self.label_2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.entry_2 = Entry(self.frame_1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.calc_button = Button(self.frame_1, text = "Calculate", command = self.function_call) # This is what doesn't work
        self.calc_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5)

    # Strips string of spaces and parentheses
    # Returns a list of relevant ordered pair
    def strip_string(self, entry_num):
        ordered_pair = entry_num.get().split(", ")
        ordered_pair[0] = ordered_pair[0].replace("(", "")
        ordered_pair[1] = ordered_pair[1].replace(")", "")
        return(ordered_pair)

    # Calculates slope based on one point and y-intercept
    def one_point(self):
        pair_1 = self.strip_string(self.entry_1)

        b = int(self.entry_2.get())
        m = (int(pair_1[1]) - b)/(float(pair_1[1]))

        label_3 = Label(self.frame_1, text = "SLOPE-INTERCEPT EQUATION:   y = " + str(m) + "x + " + str(b))
        label_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)


    # Calculates slope based on two points given
    def two_points(self):
        pair_1 = self.strip_string(self.entry_1)
        pair_2 = self.strip_string(self.entry_2)

        m = (int(pair_2[1]) - int(pair_1[1]))/float(int(pair_2[0]) - int(pair_1[0]))
        b = (int(pair_1[1])) - (m*int(pair_1[0]))

        label_3 = Label(self.frame_1, text = "SLOPE-INTERCEPT EQUATION:   y = " + str(m) + "x + " + str(b))
        label_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
  
# Calling each object
two_p = Slope_Calc(root, 0, 0, "Two Points", "First Ordered Pair", "Second Ordered Pair", "two_points")
one_p = Slope_Calc(root, 0, 1, "One Point and Y-Intercept", "Ordered Pair", "Y-intercept", "one_point")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.function_call = getattr(self, function_call)`?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `command` keyword argument of the `Button` constructor is supposed to be a function.
Here you give it instead a string which is the name of the method of `self` that should be called.  So you must first get this method using `setattr` to be able to call it.  This should do it:

```py
        def call():
            method = getattr(self, self.function_call)
            method()

        self.calc_button = Button(
            self.frame_1,
            text = "Calculate",
            command = call)
```

You then have an error in `strip_string` but that's another story.

Comment: Someone suggested I set self.function_call to getattr(self, function_call), and it worked perfectly. I appreciate the time you took to answer my question! Likewise, my strip_string function is working properly (I've added exception handling since posting). Thanks again!